# How can I call a partial view inside an ASP NET core MVC view component?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, call, partial-views

I have a footer that is a view component. Inside that footer, I have newsletter and I want to do it as a partial view.

But my footer takes a model, and my newsletter also needs a model.

Now I cannot call the Newsletter.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **ViewModel** to contain both models, you can check this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public FirstModel FirstModels { get; set; }
    public SecondModel SecondModels { get; set; }
}

public class FirstModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class SecondModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is ViewComponent's view, just need to call your ViewModel, and you can use the two

Models in MyViewModel now:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Model.FirstModels.Name  //get the name from FirstModel
<br/>
<partial name="_newsletter" model="Model.SecondModels"> //get the name from SecondModel in Partial
```

**Extra**:

The script should be defined in your _Layout.cshtml, not partial view:

```
//<html> ........</html>

<script>     
FormSuccess = function () {
    alert('you are membership now');
};
</script>
```

Form In partial view:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="NewsLetter" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="post" data-ajax-success="FormSuccess">
<input asp-for="Name">  //Email
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much . I Can solve with this solution

Comment: I want to do this way: If user send email on newsletter form after that he receive a message that :" you are membership now". I want to do it with ajax form. but I cant write my function .can you help me ? its really necessary @Tisa

Comment: @hasti.au alert("you are membership now") in ajax success. What do you mean'  cant write my function', Could you please show your related code?My guess is, you should place javascript part in _Layout, not partial.

Comment: I want to do after user send his email in newsletter after that receive a message that is successful. I put in on my controller:
/switch (newsLetter)
                //{
                //    case NewsLetterResult.EmailExist:
                //        {
                //            return Json(new
                //            {
                //                text = "Success"
         
@Tisa

Comment: but I cant write my footer.js ,said to me I should set form (Form Tag ) in ajax with som attribute. I put:    @*<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="NewsLetter"  data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="post"  data-ajax-success="FormSuccess">*@
but I cant write function FormSucess.  can you help me write this function @Tisa

Comment: I did it before this attribute. but I think its problem is for my reference. because after submit I see this:{"text":"\u0639\u0636\u0648\u06CC\u062A \u0634\u0645\u0627 \u062F\u0631 \u062E\u0628\u0631 \u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0628\u0627 \u0645\u0648\u0641\u0642\u06CC\u062A \u0627\u0646\u062C\u0627\u0645 \u0634\u062F"}

Comment: My refrence:
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
        asp-fallback-src="/bower_components/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
        asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator && window.jQuery.validator.unobtrusive">
</script>

Comment: @hasti.au You should better offer your related code and put them in your main post. Use F12 to check the script error

Comment: I see in F12.but there is not any this .so I think my reference is wrong.
I should reference unobtrusive?

Comment: @hasti.au Yes, you should added this: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive

Comment: I Cant understand the mean of this solution: <partial name="_newsletter" model="Model.SecondModels"> when I have first view model: site setting, now I need use the partial on it(email for newsletter). so I insert new property such public string NewsLetterEmail { get; set; } in the site setting viewmodel. right? then on the site seeting view model I can use : <partial name="_NewsLetter" model="@Model.NewsLetterEmail" /> @Tisa